# Python score counter

Tags: python, counter, scoring

I'm almost done with this program I'm making to help me study for my Japanese class. All I need to do is figure out how to keep track of how many I got right or wrong and then print the result afterwards. My program is kinda large, but this is what I have: (doesn't work yet the way I want it to)

```
RIGHT = 0
WRONG = 0

import random

def main():    
    study_more = 'y'

    while study_more == 'y':
        start()

        score()

        study_more = input('Do you want to study more? (y for yes): ')

def start():
    answer2 = int(input('Enter the chapter you would like to study (1-6): '))
    answer3 = int(input('Japanese to English? (1) or English to Japanese (2): '))
    print()

    if answer2 == 1 and answer3 == 1:
        ch1_japanese_to_english()
    elif answer2 == 1 and answer3 == 2:
        ch1_english_to_japanese()
    elif answer2 == 2 and answer3 == 1:
        ch2_japanese_to_english()
    elif answer2 == 2 and answer3 == 2:
        ch2_english_to_japanese()
    elif answer2 == 3 and answer3 == 1:
        ch3_japanese_to_english()
    elif answer2 == 3 and answer3 == 2:
        ch3_english_to_japanese()
    elif answer2 == 4 and answer3 == 1:
        ch4_japanese_to_english()
    elif answer2 == 4 and answer3 == 2:
        ch4_english_to_japanese()
    elif answer2 == 5 and answer3 == 1:
        ch5_japanese_to_english()
    elif answer2 == 5 and answer3 == 2:
        ch5_english_to_japanese()
    elif answer2 == 6 and answer3 == 1:
        ch6_japanese_to_english()
    elif answer2 == 6 and answer3 == 2:
        ch6_english_to_japanese()
    else:
        print("You've entered invalid responses.")

def score():

    ch1_japanese_to_english()
    ch1_english_to_japanese()    
    ch2_japanese_to_english()
    ch2_english_to_japanese()
    ch3_japanese_to_english()
    ch3_english_to_japanese()
    ch4_japanese_to_english()
    ch4_english_to_japanese()
    ch5_japanese_to_english()
    ch5_english_to_japanese()
    ch6_japanese_to_english()
    ch6_english_to_japanese()

    print('The number you got right: ', RIGHT)
    print('The number you go wrong: ', WRONG)

def ch1_japanese_to_english():
    dictionary = {'ano' : 'um', 'ima': 'now', 'eego' : 'english', 'hai' : 'yes', 'gakusei' : 'student', '...go' : 'language', 'kookoo' : 'high school', 'gogo' : 'pm', 'gozen' : 'am', '...sai' : 'years old', '...san' : 'mr/ms', '...ji' : "o'clock", '...jin' : 'people', 'senkoo' : 'major', 'sensei' : 'teacher', 'soo desu' : "that's right", 'daigaku' : 'college', 'denwa' : 'telephone', 'tomodachi' : 'friend', 'namae' : 'name', 'nani' : 'what', 'nihon' : 'japan', '...nensei' : 'year student', 'han' : 'half', 'bangoo' : 'number', 'ryuugakusei' : 'international student', 'watashi' : 'I', 'amerika' : 'america', 'igirisu' : 'britain', 'oosutoraria' : 'australia', 'kankoku' : 'korea', 'suweeden' : 'sweeden', 'chuugoku' : 'china', 'kagaku': 'science', 'ajia kenkyuu' : 'asian studies', 'keizai' : 'economics', 'kokusaikankei' : 'international relations', 'konpyuutaa' : 'computer', 'jinruigaku' : 'anthropology', 'seeji' : 'politics', 'bijinesu' : 'business', 'bungaku' : 'literature', 'rekishi' : 'history', 'shigoto' : 'occupation', 'isha' : 'doctor', 'kaishain' : 'office worker', 'kookoosei' : 'high school student', 'shufu' : 'house wife', 'daigakuinsei' : 'graduate student', 'bengoshi' : 'lawyer', 'okaasan' : 'mother', 'otoosan' : 'father', 'oneesan' : 'older sister', 'oniisan' : 'older brother', 'imooto' : 'younger sister', 'otooto': 'younger brother'}
    words = list(dictionary.items())
    random.shuffle(words)

    for word, translation in words:
        print()
        print(word)
        answer = input('Enter the translation: ')

        if answer == translation:
            print('Correct!')
            RIGHT += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.')
            print('The correct answer is: %s.' % translation)
            WRONG += 1

        print()
        return RIGHT
        return WRONG

def ch1_english_to_japanese():
    dictionary = {'um' : 'ano', 'now' : 'ima', 'english' : 'eego', 'yes' : 'hai', 'student' : 'gakusei', 'language' : 'go', 'high school' : 'kookoo', 'pm': 'gogo', 'am' : 'gozen', 'years old': 'sai', 'mr/ms' : 'san', "o'clock" : 'ji', 'people' : 'go', 'major' : 'senkoo', 'teacher' : 'sensei', "that's right" : 'soo desu', 'college' : 'daigaku', 'telephone' : 'denwa', 'friend' : 'tomodachi', 'name' : 'namae', 'what' : 'nani', 'japan' : 'nihon', 'year student' : 'nensei', 'half' : 'han', 'number' : 'bangoo', 'international student' : 'ryuugakusei', 'I' : 'watashi', 'america' : 'amerika', 'britain' : 'igirisu' , 'australia' : 'oosutoraria', 'korea' : 'kankoku', 'sweeden' : 'suweeden', 'china' : 'chuugoku', 'science' : 'kagaku', 'asian studies' : 'ajia kenkyuu', 'economics' : 'keizai', 'international relations' : 'kokusaikankei', 'computer' : 'konpyuutaa', 'anthropology' : 'jinruigaku', 'politics' : 'seeji', 'business' : 'bijinesu', 'literature' : 'bungaku', 'history' : 'rekishi', 'occupation' : 'shigoto', 'doctor' : 'isha', 'office worker' : 'kaishain', 'high school student' : 'kookoosei', 'house wife' : 'shufu', 'graduate student' : 'daigakuinsei', 'lawyer' : 'bengoshi', 'mother' : 'okaasan', 'father' : 'otoosan', 'older sister' : 'oneesan', 'older brother' : 'oniisan', 'younger sister' : 'imooto', 'younger brother' : 'otooto'}
    words = list(dictionary.items())
    random.shuffle(words)   

    for word, translation in words:
        print()
        print(word)
        answer = input('Enter the translation: ')

        if answer == translation:
            print('Correct!')
            RIGHT += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.')
            print('The correct answer is: %s.' % translation)
            WRONG += 1

        print()
        return RIGHT
        return WRONG        

def ch2_japanese_to_english():
    dictionary = {'kore' : 'this one', 'sore' : 'that one', 'are' : 'that one over there', 'dore' : 'which one', 'kono' : 'this', 'sono' : 'that', 'ano' : 'that over there', 'dono' : 'which', 'koko' : 'here', 'soko' : 'there', 'asoko' : 'over there', 'doko' : 'where', 'dare' : 'who', 'oishii' : 'delicious', 'sakana' : 'fish', 'tonkatsu' : 'pork cutlet', 'niku' : 'meat', 'menyuu' : 'menu', 'yasai' : 'vegetable', 'enpitsu' : 'pencil', 'kasa' : 'umbrella', 'kaban' : 'bag', 'kutsu' : 'shoes', 'saifu' : 'wallet', 'jiinzu' : 'jeans', 'jisho' : 'dictionary', 'jitensha' : 'bicycle', 'shinbun' : 'newspaper', 'tiishatsu' : 't-shirt', 'tokei' : 'clock', 'nooto' : 'notebook', 'pen' : 'pen', 'booshi' : 'hat', 'hon' : 'book', 'kissaten' : 'cafe', 'ginkoo' : 'bank', 'toire' : 'restroom', 'toshokan' : 'library', 'yuubinkyoku' : 'post office', 'ikura' : 'how much', 'en' : 'yen', 'takai' : 'expensive', 'irasshaimase' : 'welcome', 'onegaishimasu': 'please', 'kudasai' : 'please give me', 'jaa' : 'then', 'doozo' : 'here it is', 'doomo' : 'thank you'}
    words = list(dictionary.items())
    random.shuffle(words)   

    for word, translation in words:
        print()
        print(word)
        answer = input('Enter the translation: ')

        if answer == translation:
            print('Correct!')
            RIGHT += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.')
            print('The correct answer is: %s.' % translation)
            WRONG += 1

        print()
        return RIGHT
        return WRONG        

def ch2_english_to_japanese():
    dictionary = {'this one' : 'kore', 'that one' : 'sore', 'that one over there' : 'are', 'which one' : 'dore', 'this' : 'kono', 'that' : 'sono', 'that over there' : 'ano', 'which' : 'dono', 'here' : 'koko', 'there' : 'soko', 'over there' : 'asoko', 'where' : 'doko', 'who' : 'dare', 'delicious' : 'oishii', 'fish' : 'sakana', 'pork cutlet' : 'tonkatsu', 'meat' : 'niku', 'menu' : 'menyuu', 'vegetable' : 'yasai', 'pencil' : 'enpitsu', 'umbrella' : 'kasa', 'bag' : 'kaban', 'shoes' : 'kutsu', 'wallet' : 'saifu', 'jeans' : 'jiinzu', 'dictionary' : 'jisho', 'bicycle' : 'jitensha', 'newspaper' : 'shinbun', 't-shirt' : 'tiishatsu', 'clock' : 'tokei', 'notebook' : 'nooto', 'pen' : 'pen', 'hat' : 'booshi', 'book' : 'hon', 'cafe' : 'kissaten', 'bank' : 'ginkoo', 'restroom' : 'toire', 'library' : 'toshokan', 'post office' : 'yuubinkyoku', 'how much' : 'ikura', 'yen' : 'en', 'expensive' : 'takai', 'welcome' : 'irasshaimase', 'please' : 'onegaishimasu', 'please give me' : 'kudasai', 'then' : 'jaa', 'here it is' : 'doozo', 'thank you' : 'doomo'}
    words = list(dictionary.items())
    random.shuffle(words)  

    for word, translation in words:
        print()
        print(word)
        answer = input('Enter the translation: ')

        if answer == translation:
            print('Correct!')
            RIGHT += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.')
            print('The correct answer is: %s.' % translation)
            WRONG += 1

        print()
        return RIGHT
        return WRONG        

def ch3_japanese_to_english():
    dictionary = {'eiga' : 'movie','ongaku' : 'music','zasshi' : 'magazine','supootsu' : 'sports','deeto' : 'date','tenisu' : 'tenis','terebi' : 'tv','aisukuriimu' : 'ice cream','asagohan' : 'breakfast','osake' : 'alchohol','ocha' : 'green tea','koohii' : 'coffee','bangohan' : 'dinner','hanbaagaa' : 'hamburger','hirugohan' : 'lunch','mizu' : 'water','ie' : 'home','uchi' : 'my place','gakkoo' : 'school','asa' : 'morning','ashite' : 'tommorow','itsu' : 'when','kyoo' : 'today','goro' : 'at about','konban' : 'tonight','shuumatsu' : 'weekend','doyoobi' : 'saturday','nichiyoobi' : 'sunday','mainichi' : 'everyday','maiban' : 'every night','iku' : 'to go','kaeru' : 'to return','kiku' : 'to listen','nomu' : 'to drink','hanasu' : 'to speak','yomu' : 'to read','okiru' : 'to get up','taberu' : 'to eat','neru' : 'to sleep','miru' : 'to see','kuru' : 'to come','suru' : 'to do','benkyoosuru' : 'to study','ii' : 'good','hayai' : 'early','amari' : 'not much','zenzen' : 'not at all','taitei' : 'usually','chotto' : 'a little','tokidoki' : 'sometimes','yoku' : 'often','soo desu ne' : "that's right",'demo' : 'but','doo desu ka' : 'how about'}
    words = list(dictionary.items())
    random.shuffle(words)   

    for word, translation in words:
        print()
        print(word)
        answer = input('Enter the translation: ')

        if answer == translation:
            print('Correct!')
            RIGHT += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.')
            print('The correct answer is: %s.' % translation)
            WRONG += 1

        print()
        return RIGHT
        return WRONG        

def ch3_english_to_japanese():
    dictionary = {'movie' : 'eiga','music' : 'ongaku','magazine' : 'zasshi','sports' : 'supootsu','date' : 'deeto','tenis' : 'tenisu','tv' : 'terebi','ice cream' : 'aisukuriimu','breakfast' : 'asagohan','alchohol' : 'osake','green tea' : 'ocha','coffee' : 'koohii','dinner' : 'bangohan','hamburger' : 'hanbaagaa','lunch' : 'hirugohan','water' : 'mizu','home' : 'ie','my place' : 'uchi','school' : 'gakkoo','morning' : 'asa','tommorow' : 'ashite','when' : 'itsu','today' : 'kyoo','at about' : 'goro','tonight' : 'konban','weekend' : 'shuumatsu','saturday' : 'doyoobi','sunday' : 'nichiyoobi','everyday' : 'mainichi','every night' : 'maiban','to go' : 'iku','to return' : 'kaeru','to listen' : 'kiku','to drink' : 'nomu','to speak' : 'hanasu','to read' : 'yomu','to get up' : 'okiru','to eat' : 'taberu','to sleep' : 'neru','to see' : 'miru','to come' : 'kuru','to do' : 'suru','to study' : 'benkyoosuru','good' : 'ii','early' : 'hayai','not much' : 'amari','not at all' : 'zenzen','usually' : 'taitei','a little' : 'chotto','sometimes' : 'tokidoki','often' : 'yoku',"that's right" : 'soo desu ne','demo' : 'but','doo desu ka' : 'how about'}
    words = list(dictionary.items())
    random.shuffle(words)  

    for word, translation in words:
        print()
        print(word)
        answer = input('Enter the translation: ')

        if answer == translation:
            print('Correct!')
            RIGHT += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.')
            print('The correct answer is: %s.' % translation)
            WRONG += 1

        print() 
        return RIGHT
        return WRONG        

def ch4_japanese_to_english():
    dictionary = {'arubaito' : 'part time job','kaimono' : 'shopping','kurasu' : 'class','anata' : 'you','isu' : 'chair','inu' : 'dog','amiyage' : 'souvenir','kodomo' : 'child','gohan' : 'meal','shashin' : 'picture','tsukue' : 'desk','tegami' : 'letter','neko' : 'cat','paso' : 'bread','hito' : 'person','meeru' : 'e-mail','otera' : 'temple','kooen' : 'park','suupaa' : 'supermarket','depaato' : 'department store','basutei' : 'bus stop','byooin' : 'hospital','hoteru' : 'hotel','honya' : 'bookstore','machi' : 'city','resutoran' : 'restaurant','kinoo' : 'yesterday','jikan' : 'hours','ichijikan' : 'one hour','senshuu' : 'last week','toki' : 'when','getsuyoobi' : 'monday','kayoobi' : 'tuesday','suiyoobi' : 'wednesday','mokuyoobi' : 'thursday','kinyoobi' : 'friday','au' : 'to meet','aru' : 'there is','kau' : 'to buy','kaku' : 'to write','toru' : 'to take','matsu' : 'to wait','wakaru' : 'to understand','iru' : 'is in','gurai' : 'about','gomennasai' : "I'm sorry",'dakara' : 'so','takusan' : 'many','to' : 'together with','dooshite' : 'why','hitoride' : 'alone','migi' : 'right','hidari' : 'left','mae' : 'front', 'ushiro' : 'back', 'naka' : 'inside', 'ue' : 'on', 'shita' : 'under', 'chikaku' : 'near', 'tonari' : 'next', 'aida' : 'between'}
    words = list(dictionary.items())
    random.shuffle(words)  

    for word, translation in words:
        print()
        print(word)
        answer = input('Enter the translation: ')

        if answer == translation:
            print('Correct!')
            RIGHT += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.')
            print('The correct answer is: %s.' % translation)
            WRONG += 1

        print()  
        return RIGHT
        return WRONG        

def ch4_english_to_japanese():
    dictionary = {'part time job' : 'arubaito','shopping' : 'kaimono','class' : 'kurasu','you' : 'anata','chair' : 'isu','dog' : 'inu','souvenir' : 'omiyage','child' : 'kodomo','meal' : 'gohan','picture' : 'shashin','desk' : 'tsukue','letter' : 'tegami','cat' : 'neko','bread' : 'paso','person' : 'hito','e-mail' : 'meeru','temple' : 'otera','park' : 'kooen','supermarket' : 'suupaa','department store' : 'depaato','bus stop' : 'basutei','hospital' : 'byooin','hotel' : 'hoteru','bookstore' : 'honya','city' : 'machi','restaurant' : 'resutoran','yesterday' : 'kinoo','hours' : 'jikan','one hour' : 'ichijikan','last week' : 'senshuu','when' : 'toki','monday' : 'getsuyoobi','tuesday' : 'kayoobi','wednesday' : 'suiyoobi','thursday' : 'mokuyoobi','friday' : 'kinyoobi','to meet' : 'au','there is' : 'aru','to buy' : 'kau','to write' : 'kaku','to take' : 'toru','to wait' : 'matsu','to understand' : 'wakaru','is in' : 'iru','about' : 'gurai',"I'm sorry" : 'gomennasai','so' : 'dakara','many' : 'takusan','together with' : 'to','why' : 'dooshite','alone' : 'hitoride','right' : 'migi','left' : 'hidari','front' : 'mae', 'back' : 'ushiro', 'inside' : 'naka', 'on' : 'ue', 'under' : 'shita', 'near' : 'chikaku', 'next' : 'tonari', 'between' : 'aida'}
    words = list(dictionary.items())
    random.shuffle(words)  

    for word, translation in words:
        print()
        print(word)
        answer = input('Enter the translation: ')

        if answer == translation:
            print('Correct!')
            RIGHT += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.')
            print('The correct answer is: %s.' % translation)
            WRONG += 1

        print()
        return RIGHT
        return WRONG        

def ch5_japanese_to_english():
    dictionary = {'umi' : 'sea','kitte' : 'postal stamps','kippu' : 'ticket','saafuin' : 'surfing','shukudai' : 'homework','tabemono' : 'food','tanjoobi' : 'birthday','tesuto' : 'test','tenki' : 'weather','nomimono' : 'drink','hagaki' : 'post card','basu' : 'bus','hikooki' : 'airplane','heya' : 'room','boku' : 'I','yasumi' : 'holiday','ruogoo' : 'travel','atarashii' : 'new','atsui' : 'hot','isogashii' : 'busy','ookii' : 'large','omoshiroi' : 'interesting','kakkoii' : 'good looking','kowai' : 'frightening','samui' : 'cold','tanoshii' : 'fun','chiisai' : 'small','tsumaranai' : 'boring','furui' : 'old','muzukashii' : 'difficult','yasashii' : 'easy','yasui' : 'cheap','kirai' : 'to dislike','kirei' : 'beautiful','genki' : 'healthy','shizuka' : 'quiet','suki' : 'to like','daikirai' : 'to hate','daisuki' : 'to love','nigiyaka' : 'lively','hima' : 'not busy','oyogu' : 'to swim','kiku' : 'to ask','noru' : 'to ride','yaru' : 'to do','dekakeru' : 'to go out','isshoni' : 'together','sugoku' : 'extreamly','sorekara' : 'and then','daijoobu' : "it's okay",'totemo' : 'very','donna' : 'what kind of'}
    words = list(dictionary.items())
    random.shuffle(words)  

    for word, translation in words:
        print()
        print(word)
        answer = input('Enter the translation: ')

        if answer == translation:
            print('Correct!')
            RIGHT += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.')
            print('The correct answer is: %s.' % translation)
            WRONG += 1

        print()  
        return RIGHT
        return WRONG        

def ch5_english_to_japanese():
    dictionary = {'sea' : 'umi','postal stamps' : 'kitte','ticket' : 'kippu','surfing' : 'saafuin','homework' : 'shukudai','food' : 'tabemono','birthday' : 'tanjoobi','test' : 'tesuto','weather' : 'tenki','drink' : 'nomimono','post card' : 'hagaki','bus' : 'basu','airplane' : 'hikooki','room' : 'heya','I' : 'boku','holiday' : 'yasumi','travel' : 'ryogoo','new' : 'atarashii','hot' : 'atsui','busy' : 'isogashii','large' : 'ookii','interesting' : 'omoshiroi','good looking' : 'kakkoii','frightening' : 'kowai','cold' : 'samui','fun' : 'tanoshii','small' : 'chiisai','boring' : 'tsumaranai','old' : 'furui','difficult' : 'muzukashii','easy' : 'yasashii','chaep' : 'yasui','to dislike' : 'kirai','beautiful' : 'kirei','healthy' : 'genki','quiet' : 'shizuka','to like' : 'suki','to hate' : 'dakirai','to love' : 'daisuki','lively' : 'nigiyaka','not busy' : 'hima','to swim' : 'oyogu','to ask' : 'kiku','to ride' : 'noru','to do' : 'yaru','to go out' : 'dekakeru','together' : 'isshoni','extreamly' : 'sugoku','and then' : 'sorekara',"it's okay" : 'daijoobu','very' : 'totemo','what kind of' : 'donna'}
    words = list(dictionary.items())
    random.shuffle(words)   

    for word, translation in words:
        print()
        print(word)
        answer = input('Enter the translation: ')

        if answer == translation:
            print('Correct!')
            RIGHT += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.')
            print('The correct answer is: %s.' % translation)
            WRONG += 1

        print() 
        return RIGHT
        return WRONG        

def ch6_japanese_to_english():
    dictionary = {'okane' : 'money','ofuro' : 'bath','kanji' : 'kanji','kyookasho' : 'textbook','konshuu' : 'this weeek','shiidii' : 'cd','shiminbyooin' : 'municipal hospital','shiyawaa' : 'shower','tsugi' : 'next','denki' : 'electricity','densha' : 'train','nimotsu' : 'baggage','pasokon' : 'personal computer','peeji' : 'page','mado' : 'window','yoru' : 'night','raishuu' : 'next week','rainen' : 'next year','taihen' : 'tough','asobu' : 'to play','isogu' : 'to hurry','ofuronihairu' : 'to take a bath','kaesu' : 'to return','kesu' : 'to turn off','shinu' : 'to die','suwaru' : 'to sit down','tatsu' : 'to stand up','tabaiwosuu' : 'to smoke','tsukau' : 'to use','tetsudau' : 'to help','hairu' : 'to enter','motsu' : 'to carry','yasumu' : 'to be absent','akeru' : 'to open','oshieru' : 'to teach','oriru' : 'to get off','kariru' : 'to borrow','shinuru' : 'to close','shiyawaawoabiru' : 'to take a shower','to turn on' : 'tsukeru','to make a phone call' : 'denwawokakeru','wasureru' : 'to forget','tsuretekuru' : 'to bring a person','mottekuru' : 'to bringa  thing','atode' : 'later on','osoku' : 'do something late','kara' : 'because','kekkoo desu' : 'that would be fine','sugu' : 'right away','honto desu ka' : 'really?','yukkuri' : 'slowly'}
    words = list(dictionary.items())
    random.shuffle(words)   

    for word, translation in words:
        print()
        print(word)
        answer = input('Enter the translation: ')

        if answer == translation:
            print('Correct!')
            RIGHT += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.')
            print('The correct answer is: %s.' % translation)
            WRONG += 1

        print() 
        return RIGHT
        return WRONG        

def ch6_english_to_japanese():
    dictionary = {'money' : 'okane','bath' : 'ofuro','kanji' : 'kanji','textbook' : 'kyookasho','this week' : 'konshuu','cd' : 'shiidii','municipal hospital' : 'shiminbyooin','shower' : 'shiyawaa','next' : 'tsugi','electricity' : 'denki','train' : 'densha','baggage' : 'nimotsu','personal computer' : 'pasokon','page' : 'peeji','window' : 'mado','night' : 'yoru','next week' : 'raishuu','next year' : 'rainen','tough' : 'taihen','to play' : 'asobu','to hurry' : 'isogu','to take a bath' : 'ofuronihairu','to return' : 'kaesu','to turn off' : 'kesu','to die' : 'shinu','to sit down' : 'suwaru','to stand up' : 'tatsu','to smoke' : 'tabaiwosuu','to use' : 'tsukau','to help' : 'tetsudau','to enter' : 'hairu','to carry' : 'motsu','to be absent' : 'yasumu','to open' : 'akeru','to teach' : 'oshieru','to get off' : 'oriru','to borrow' : 'kariru','to close' : 'shinuru','to take a shower' : 'shiyawaawoabiru','to turn on' : 'tsukeru','to make a phone call' : 'denwawokakeru','to forget' : 'wasureru','to bring a person' : 'tsuretekuru','to bring a thing' : 'mottekuru','later on' : 'atode','do something late' : 'osoku','because' : 'kara','that would be fine' : 'kekkoo desu','right away' : 'sugu','really?' : 'hontoo desu ka','slowly' : 'yukkuri'}
    words = list(dictionary.items())
    random.shuffle(words)   

    for word, translation in words:
        print()
        print(word)
        answer = input('Enter the translation: ')

        if answer == translation:
            print('Correct!')
            RIGHT += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.')
            print('The correct answer is: %s.' % translation)
            WRONG += 1

        print()
        return RIGHT
        return WRONG        

main()
```

Comment: sooo much code duplication ...

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work yet the way I want it to?" There's a lot of code here. Show us the relevant section, what you expect, and what it's doing.

Comment: It's basically the same program just for different chapters and vocab. I just need helping keeping score

Comment: There are a lot of ways to keep score. What's your **specific** problem?

Comment: Also, if you want to return a count of right and wrong, you should be returning a tuple: `(RIGHT, WRONG)`. A function can only have one return value (the second `return` will never be visited).

Comment: if I take out the returns I get an error saying that the local variable 'RIGHT' or the local variable 'WRONG' is referenced before assignment.

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't really what you asked, so apologies if this is an actual assignment, in which case this likely won't be helpful. As others have mentioned, there is a lot of duplication in your code. The things that stand out are: the essentially identical functions that handle the actual quizzing and (to a smaller degree) the number of `if` statements involved in interpreting the response. The general idea of the code below is to condense all of that down into one `Quiz` function, and store all of the quiz words in a different module. Regarding the chapter words, since the chapter dictionaries are actually identical, just reversed, you can use:

```
words = {v: k for k, v in words.items()}
```

to 'reverse' it in the case you want to go from English -> Japanese. Then, once you are done, the scores can just be printed. This could be further optimized, but hopefully this will get you started:

```
import random
import quiz_vocab

CHAPTER_WORDS = {
    1: quiz_vocab.chapter_1,
    2: quiz_vocab.chapter_2
    }


def main():
    study_more = 'y'
    right = 0
    wrong = 0

    while study_more == 'y':
      chapter = int(input('Enter the chapter you would like to study (1-6): '))
      direction = int(input('Japanese to English? (1) or English to Japanese (2): '))

      # Do additional handling here to make sure they pick the right stuff
      if chapter not in CHAPTER_WORDS or direction not in (1, 2):
        print("You've entered invalid responses.")
        continue
      print()

      # Return the results of quiz into their respective variables
      # and increment the overall totals
      num_right, num_wrong = quiz(chapter, direction)
      total_right += num_right
      total_wrong += num_wrong

      # Cycle again
      study_more = input('Do you want to study more? (y for yes): ')

    # Print the final total
    print('Right: {0}\nWrong: {1}'.format(total_right, total_wrong))


def quiz(chapter, direction):
    right, wrong = 0, 0

    # Get the words corresponding to the input
    words = CHAPTER_WORDS[chapter]

    # If we decide to go English -> Japanese, reverse the dictionary
    if direction == 2:
      words = {v: k for k, v in words.items()}

    # This is all the same as yours...
    words = list(words.items())
    random.shuffle(words)

    for word, translation in words:
        print()
        print(word)
        answer = input('Enter the translation: ')

        if answer == translation:
            print('Correct!')
            right += 1
        else:
            print('Incorrect.')
            print('The correct answer is: %s.' % translation)
            wrong += 1

    # Return the right/wrong counts
    return right, wrong

main()
```

And the `quiz_vocab` module looks like:

```
chapter_1 = {'ano' : 'um', 'ima': 'now', 'eego' : 'english'} # continues...
```

Comment: Great answer, but I suggest taking a look at [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for code style. (Python variables should be lower case, CamelCase is reserved for classes, and 4 space blocks are standard.)

Comment: @David Ha, what makes it even worse is that making it PEP 8 compliant is what I usually spend the most time on :) I was initially going to keep things as close to the OP's code as possible, but ended up with the patchwork above. Plus, my Vim is default two space indent - all kinds of messes going on :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like you want the user to choose what test to run (in `start()`), but then you run all the tests again from within `score()`.

If you're keeping track of the number of correct/incorrect answers in a global variable (shouldn't do it, but that's a different question), then the `score()` function should just print the value of the global variable.

By the way, the test functions don't need to return the value of the variables as you're modifying the global variables directly. And the double return statements don't make sense anyway. The function returns on the first statement, never gets to the second one.

Answer (score 1):

One mistake I see straight away is that the variables `RIGHT` and `WRONG` are referenced before assignment within your 'chapter' functions. Each function must include `global RIGHT, WRONG`

Moreover to make your program considerably smaller you can employ the following within `start` function:

```
answer1 = raw_input('Enter the chapter you would like to study (1-6): ')
answer2 = input('Japanese to English? (1) or English to Japanese (2): ')

if answer1 in range(1,7) and answer2 in [1,2]:
    functionName = 'ch{}_{}()'.format(answer1, ['japanese_to_english', 'english_tojapanese'][answer2-1])
    eval(functionName)
```

That would replace all the `if elif` clauses

---

One more improvement I can suggest is that rather than having a function for each chapter you can have a list of all the dictionaries(since they are the only things different in each 'chapter' function)of all the functions in serial order. Then have just one function which accepts `answer1` and `answer2` as arguements and accordingly selects the required dictionary. For example:

```
j_to_e = [ # all the japanese to english dictionaries in order as a list]
e_to_j = [ # all the english to japanese dictionaries in order as a list]
all_dicts = [j_to_e, e_to_j]

def chapter(chapterNumber, j_to_e):
    global RIGHT, WRONG
    curDict = all_dicts[j_to_e-1][chapterNumber-1] # '-1' to compensate 0 based lists
    words = list(curDict.items())
    random.shuffle(words)

    for word, translation in words:
        # all the function code 
        ...
        print()
        return RIGHT, WRONG  # RIGHT and WRONG should be returned on the same line otherwise 'return WRONG' won't be executed
```

The above improvements would make your code significantly concise.
Hope this helps.

Comment: as suggested by @RocketDonkey as the `j_to_e` and `e_to_j` dictionaries are just inverse of each other you can save a lot of memory by using just one of those and manipulating them as needed. I didn't notice their similarity the first time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with this code.

1. **Redundant code**: As @Joran points out, there's an enormous amount of code duplication. Functions should be *generalizable*. Each function asks for user input, then checks if it matches the dictionary's stored value. The only thing that changes is the dictionary. Why not make one "quizzing" function, and pass in the dictionary?
2. **Global variables:** Very bad. I'll leave it to you to research why, but your functions should not be modifying a global right/wrong count.
3. **Verbose code**: An enormous if/else block is a sign of un-Pythonic code. Consider following the advice given in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692263/python-string-or-if-statement-issue).

Combining all this, your generalized quizzing function should look something like this:

```
def quiz(word_dict):
    """ Quiz the user on a word dictionary, returning right/wrong count. """
    right = wrong = 0  # Initialize local count
    words = list(word_dict.items())
    random.shuffle(words)

    for word, translation in words:
        print(word)
        answer = input('Enter the translation: ')
        # (...)
    return (right, wrong)
```

A quizzing session should consist of prompting the user for the chapter, selecting the appropriate dictionary, then calling the quizzing function.